# How to show the query made by Hibernate 5.5.6

Tags: java, hibernate

It's my day 3 with Hibernate. I'm using `Hibernate 5.5.6`

**pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.26</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I think my **hibernate.cfg.xml** is also correct:

```
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">cosmonauts</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql=true"></property>
</session-factory>
```

**App.java**

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Planet telusko = new Planet();
        telusko.setAid(100);
        telusko.setAname("Tanzeel");
        telusko.setAcolor("Red");
        
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure().addAnnotatedClass(Planet.class);
        
        StandardServiceRegistry reg = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
        SessionFactory sf = configuration.buildSessionFactory(reg);
        
        Session session = sf.openSession();
        
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(telusko);
        tx.commit();
    }
}
```

Yes, the data is inserted properly but I'm not able to see the query:

**console**

```
Aug 21, 2021 12:59:44 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.5.6.Final
Aug 21, 2021 12:59:44 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
Aug 21, 2021 12:59:44 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Aug 21, 2021 12:59:44 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb]
Aug 21, 2021 12:59:44 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=root}
Aug 21, 2021 12:59:44 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Aug 21, 2021 12:59:44 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Aug 21, 2021 12:59:45 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Aug 21, 2021 12:59:45 PM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@424de326] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Aug 21, 2021 12:59:45 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
```

Please point out my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the property

```
<property name="hibernate.show_sql=true"></property>
```

to

```
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
```

Comment: Yes, this worked. Also is there any material which is using `Hibernate 5.5.6`. Because the youtube series that I'm watching is 4 years old. this way I'll keep on running into small-small issues like this one. Please suggest latest links to avoid future questions like this. Thanks